# Is there a better fix for this problem with Legended in DateListPlot?

Tags: legending, date-and-time

```
data = {{{{2010, 3, 31}, 100.}, {{2010, 9, 30}, 110.}},
   {{{2010, 3, 31}, 80.}, {{2010, 9, 30}, 90.}}};

DateListPlot[data]
```

[image]

With only two data points in all the series, in `Legended` nothing shows.

```
DateListPlot[{
  Legended[data[[1]], "A"],
  Legended[data[[2]], "B"]}]
```

[image]

One solution is to add an intermediate data point.

```
data = If[Length[#] == 2, Insert[#,
      {DateList[Mean[AbsoluteTime@*First /@ #]],
       Mean[Last /@ #]}, 2], #] & /@ data;

DateListPlot[{
  Legended[data[[1]], "A"],
  Legended[data[[2]], "B"]}]
```

[image]

This is in Mathematica 11.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: why not `DateListPlot[data, PlotLegends->{"A","B"}]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes, that works.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ok to use `PlotLegends` instead, no pre-processing is needed:

```
DateListPlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"A","B"}]
```

[image]

If you *have to* use `Legended`, you can repeat the last element of two-element data sets:

```
data2 = Map[PadRight[#, {Max[3, Length  @ #], Automatic}, Last @ #]&] @ data;

DateListPlot[{Legended[data2[[1]], "A"],  Legended[data2[[2]], "B"]}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Another option is to have the empy list `{{,}}` instead of repeating a data set. This is a strange problem, not something I would expect from something as robust as Mathematica.